# Symfony3, override Exception Controller

Tags: symfony

I try to override Exception Controller with Symfony 3
I followed their example here http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html but it doesn't work

So first I have created my error page in app/Ressources/TwigBundle.../error404.html.twig

And it works without the controller overriding.

Second, I have added in services.yml, under services:

```
frontBundle\Controller\CustomExceptionController:
    public: true
    arguments:
        $debug: '%kernel.debug%'
```

Third in my Controller folder, I have created a CustomExceptionController.php
Inside, I have put (I want to override findtemple() for example)

```
namespace frontBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateReference;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class CustomExceptionController extends ExceptionController
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param string  $format
     * @param int     $code       An HTTP response status code
     * @param bool    $showException
     *
     * @return TemplateReferenceInterface
     */
    protected function findTemplate(Request $request, $format, $code, 
$showException)
    {

    }
}
```

However it doesn't work. This new controller is not taken into consideration and the findTemplate() is not overrided.

Did I miss something?

There are really not a lot of help about that with Symfony 3...

Thank you so much

Comment: I precise that I put some code inside protected function findTemplate() which is just a path to a new error404 page name, just to test

Comment: Did you add the twig `exception_controller` setting inside your `config.yml` (as stated in your link)?

Comment: @ccKep : when I add the "exception_controller: frontBundle:Exception:showException" I have a "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException'... "

Comment: @ccKep : but do I have to add that line under twig: in my config,yml? Because in Symfony documentation it says: Instead of creating a new exception controller from scratch you can, of course, also extend the default ExceptionController... I am lost, if someone has a clear example it would be great. Thank you.

Comment: It'd probably be `frontBundle:CustomException:show` if you extend the default exception controller. (Since your controller is called `CustomExceptionController` and the inherited method is called `showAction`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need override the controller try this:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        # ... be sure autowiring is enabled
        autowire: true
    # ...

    AppBundle\Controller\CustomExceptionController:
        public: true
        arguments:
            $debug: '%kernel.debug%'
```

and:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    exception_controller: AppBundle:Exception:showException
```

[Link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#custom-exception-controller)

Regards

Comment: I added "exception_controller: AppBundle:Exception:showException" and replaced AppBundle by frontBundle and I have an error (see comment above). Do I have to create more file with that?